# Mechanism for the intra-molecular exchange of an ester and a nitrile group

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, esters, nitriles

> When the isolated product **4** is treated with sodium ethoxide in ethanol it rearranges to **5** as shown:
>
> [image]

My TA says that you need to start with a reverse Claisen at the ketone but I am not quite sure where to go from there. I do not know how to move the nitrile alpha to the carbonyl furthest from the methyl group.

Comment: Have the anion next to the CN attack the ketone. When the tetrahedral intermediate breaks down the anion of the ester leaves giving on workup 5

Comment: A good exercise to solving this type of problem is trying to map the carbons of the reactant onto the carbons of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a reasonable suggestion for the rearrangement:

[image: Acid catalyzed rearrangement]